# MessageQueue BeginReceive() method called twice

Tags: c#, message-queue, beginreceive

What will happen if I call the `BeginReceive()` method twice (one after the other)?

Example:

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue("strQueueConnectionhere");
mq.BeginReceive(); // first call
mq.BeginReceive(); // second call
```

Pls help

thnx :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two asynchronise '`BeginReceive`' calls waiting for a message to go onto the queue.  I'm guessing that when a message pops on, then one of those will handle it and will finish with the `ReceiveCompleted` event while the other one waits for the next message.  If you don't handle the `ReceiveCompleted` event, then you won't see anything happen.

Comment: will it not disregard the first BeginReceive?